# How to find calculations of 2D string arrays in double format C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, console-application

I have a Console Application in C# that allows a user to input 5 days of the week and then 5 numerical values corresponding with the days in a single 2D array.

The array is in string format so I tried to Parse the second half of the string data and produce a sum of them but it says my index is out of bounds, any ideas?

Code posted below:

```cs
//Ask the user to enter five days of the week and rainfall data for each day

double rainsum = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Please enter 5 days of the week.");

//Store the data in a two dimensional string array named rainfallData[]
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
  {
    rainfallData[i, j] = Console.ReadLine();
  }
  if (i == 0)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the corresponding rain data.");
  }
}

Console.WriteLine("Data placed in raindallData[] array.");

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine();
  for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("rainfallData({0},{1})={2}", i, j, rainfallData[i, j]);
  }
}

//Use iteration to calculate the following from the values in rainfallData[]:
//a) sum
Console.Write("Data values calculated using iteration. \n a) Sum of rainfallData[] = ");
for (int i = 1; i < rainfallData.Length; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine();
  for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
  {
    rainsum += double.Parse(rainfallData[i, j]);
  }
}
Console.WriteLine(rainsum);

//End Program
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Comment: Don't use 2d arrays. They are always messy to work with. Use jaggard arrays - i.e. `string[][]`.

Comment: Do you think it might be important to show the declaration of `rainfallData` since you have a "index is out of bounds" error?

Comment: Did you ever wonder what the value of `rainfallData.Length` is?

Comment: Add some output to assist with debugging this error. After printing _Data values calculated using iteration_, add `Console.WriteLine(rainfallData.Length)` - this will tell you how many times the outer loop iterates. Above the line `rainsum += double.Parse(rainfallData[i, j]);`, add `Console.WriteLine(rainfallData[i, j])` - this will tell you at what index the error occurs.

Comment: I've got to use this stupid string array for an assignment :/ 

I'll update with the declaration of rainfallData!

So i just changed rainfallData.Length to 2 and that fixed the problem??? any idea why?

Comment: Also, the outer loop `for (int i = 1; i < rainfallData.Length; i++)` is not necessary. Why not remove the loop and replace `rainfallData[i, j]` with `rainfallData[1, j]` (note `i` replaced with `1`)?

Comment: @Morg - So you should have added the [homework] tag?

Comment: wow i didn't know they had that! I'll use it next time for sure thanks

Comment: okay now a weird question...

I must use iteration to find the lowest value of the rainfall data.
I just found out that Array.Sort only work for 1D arrays and we havent covered anything regarding sorting multidimensional arrays...

Is there any way to use a for loop to take rainfallData[1,0-4] and put those values in a 1D array? 

I'm trying to visualize some way to use iteration and still find that lowest value but frankly I'm stumped.

Comment: so for now I have manually entered each data value from rainfallData[1,0-4] into a new array rainValues[0-4] and I think I'm just going to use Array.Sort to find the lowest value like that..... It's a little more on the scenic route but it's the best I've got rn hahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `rainfallData.Length` refers to the number of items in the 2d array - in your case this is `2 x 5 = 10`, but you were putting that index in the first dimension and causing the out of bound error.

If I were you I would have started my code like this:

```
int columns = 2;
int days = 5;

string [,] rainfallData = new string[columns, days];
```

Now each and every time that refer to the bounds of each dimension use `columns` and `days` respectively.

The you'd write your code this way:

```
//Ask the user to enter five days of the week and rainfall data for each day
Console.WriteLine("Please enter 5 days of the week.");

//Store the data in a two dimensional string array named rainfallData[]

for (int j = 0; j < days; j++)
{
    rainfallData[0, j] = Console.ReadLine();
}
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the corresponding rain data.");
for (int j = 0; j < days; j++)
{
    rainfallData[1, j] = Console.ReadLine();
}

Console.WriteLine("Data placed in raindallData[] array.");

for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    for (int j = 0; j < days; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("rainfallData({0},{1})={2}", i, j, rainfallData[i, j]);
    }
}

//Use iteration to calculate the following from the values in rainfallData[]:
//a) sum
double rainsum = 0.0;
Console.Write("Data values calculated using iteration. \n a) Sum of rainfallData[] = ");
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    for (int j = 0; j < days; j++)
    {
        rainsum += double.Parse(rainfallData[i, j]);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(rainsum);
```

---

Just for your edification here's how I might have really tackled this:

```
int days = 5;

Console.WriteLine("Please enter 5 days of the week.");
string[] first = Enumerable.Range(0, days).Select(x => Console.ReadLine()).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine("Please enter the corresponding rain data.");
string[] second = Enumerable.Range(0, days).Select(x => Console.ReadLine()).ToArray();

string[][] rainfallData = new[] { first, second };

Console.WriteLine("Data placed in raindallData[][] jaggard array.");
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", Enumerable.Range(0, days).Select(x => $"rainfallData[0][{1}]={rainfallData[0][x]}\n")));

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable.Range(0, days).Select(x => $"rainfallData[1][{1}]={rainfallData[1][x]}")));

double rainsum = rainfallData.Sum(i => i.Sum(j => double.Parse(j)));
Console.WriteLine($"Data values calculated using iteration. \n a) Sum of rainfallData[][] = {rainsum}");
```

---

Here's an even more robust way:

```
double[] readNumbers(int items, string title)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Please enter {items} of {title} data.");
    int attempt = 0;
    return
        Enumerable
            .Range(0, items)
            .Select(x =>
            {
                double result;
                while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Input not a number. Please try again.");
                }
                return result;
            })
            .ToArray();
}

int days = 5;

double[] first = readNumbers(days, "first columnn");
double[] second = readNumbers(days, "rain data");

double[][] rainfallData = new[] { first, second };

Console.WriteLine("Data placed in raindallData[][] jaggard array.");
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", Enumerable.Range(0, days).Select(x => $"rainfallData[0][{1}]={rainfallData[0][x]}\n")));

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable.Range(0, days).Select(x => $"rainfallData[1][{1}]={rainfallData[1][x]}")));

double rainsum = rainfallData.Sum(i => i.Sum());
Console.WriteLine($"Data values calculated using iteration. \n a) Sum of rainfallData[][] = {rainsum}");
```

Comment: Thanks so much!

Some of the terms in the way you tackled it go over my head, but I have to use jagged arrays for the final part of this assignment and this will definitely help me get a better feel for how I should go about that.

I can't thank you enough!! Programming gets very intimidating when you start running into walls hahaha